# Clarity in providing multiple parameters to the function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

I would like to provide multiple parameters to the Javascript function, and also having clarity regarding passed parameters, so having this function

```
var callMe = function (param1, param2, param3) {
  console.log(param1 + ", " + param2 + ", " + param3) 
}
```

I would call the method **callMe()** like this, having in mind that value of parameter initialization is the value itself:

```
callMe(param1 = 1, param2 = 2, param3 = 3)
```

My goal is to have clarity when providing multiple parameters to avoid confusion.

Are there any negative effects in the example above, or may be I'm just trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: No sense in naming an anonymous function since its name cant be used for anything, and probably would lead to confusion in thinking that you could somewhere call `callMe` when you actually cant. I guess it provides a label, but then again you should name your functions for what they do and not just some meaningless letter etc.

Comment: I agree, fixed the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not declaring your params ahead of time with a `var`, you're introducing global variables like crazy. And I can imagine that it'd get very, very sloppy very quickly. Instead of doing that, use a configuration object as the argument. Though it has its own drawbacks, you are essentially doing the same thing while wrapping the args in a way that it doesn't (as you say) reinvent the wheel. So..

```
var f = function (config) {
    console.log(config.param1 + ", " + config.param2 + ", " + config.param3);
}

f({
    param1: "Foo",
    param2: "Bar",
    param3: "Baz"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
var callMe = {
              param1:1,
              param2:2,
              param3:3
};
```